# Sending message to specific channel in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, discord.js

I want to send a message to a specific channel but it doesn't work, I've tried
`client.guilds.cache.get("<id>").send("<msg>")`
but I get the error ".send is not a function".
What am I missing here?

Comment: _What am I missing here?_ Getting the channel. `client.guilds.cache.get("<id>")` returns a guild, not a channel.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways of sending message to a specific channel.

**1. Using a fetch method**

```
const channel = await <client>.channels.fetch('channelID')
channel.send({content: "Example Message"})
```

**2. Using a get method**

```
const channel = await <client>.channels.cache.get('channelID')
channel.send({content: "Example Message"})
```

**3. Using a find method**

***a.***

```
const channel = await <client>.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "channelID")
channel.send({content: "Example Message"})
```

***b.***

```
const channel = await <client>.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channelName")
channel.send({content: "Example Message})
```

*Your current code line is getting the GUILD_ID not the CHANNEL_ID.*

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get from the cache a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild) not a [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Channel), or more specifically a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel), that's why what you try is not working, you should try to change the code to something like this and it should work.

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('Channel Id');
channel.send({ content: 'This is a message' });
```

Also, as something extra, I would recommend using the [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) method for these things, since it checks the bot's cache and in the case of not finding the requested object it sends a request to the api, but it depends on the final use if you need it or not.

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('Channel Id');
channel.send({ content: 'This is a message' });
```