# Discord.JS | How do I make it fetch a channel by ID?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need it to fetch a channel id but I don't know how code:

```
            fetch(, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                avatar_url: '',
                embeds: [
                  {
                    color: 3092790,
                    title: `${emoji.info} **New User**`,
```

I tried using other posts and AI but they failed.

Comment: it is complete its just I didnt send the full thing, it was sending messages throguh webhooks so they were getting pinged a lot by exploiters, so i'm trying to use the bot to send embeds to a channel using fetch

Comment: I Didn't send it fully I Only need help with the fetch

Comment: Do you use discord.js? You use the tag but try to use `fetch` for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some more of your code, just with private information (like server URLs, keys, etc.) redacted? Without knowing what URL you're `fetch`ing at, and the rest of the `body`, it'll be hard to see what's wrong. If you're trying to do a specific thing (like get a channel ID), you might also be able to look at some examples in the documentation or on GitHub.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71432497/15353979